# Successcallback and Errorcallback in my plugin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Hi Im currently trying to call the Successcallback and my Errorcallback in my plugin. Im using ionic v1 it seems that it display all the consoles of success and errors..

This is the plugin I use

```
var exec = require('cordova/exec');
var cordova = require('cordova');

var triangle = {

    initialize: function(applicationId, accessKey, secretKey, successCallback, errorCallback) {
        // Define document events used by the API
        cordova.addDocumentEventHandler('ontaperror');
        cordova.addDocumentEventHandler('ontapsuccess');
        cordova.addDocumentEventHandler('ontapdetect');

        // Call the Android side to initialize the Triangle session
        exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "Triangle", "initialize", [applicationId, accessKey, secretKey]);
    }
}

module.exports = triangle;
```

and this is in my controller to call the success and error callbacks

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', scanCreditCard, false);

    function scanCreditCard() {

        navigator.triangle.initialize(
            "My Application ID", // application ID
            "Access Key", // access key
            "SecretKey", // secret key
           succcessCallack(),    
           errorCallback() 

        );
    };


    function succcessCallack() {

        console.log("Ready to scan")

        // Subscribe to events that the Triangle APIs raise
        document.addEventListener('ontaperror', onTapError(), false);
        document.addEventListener('ontapdetect', onTapDetect(), false);
        document.addEventListener('ontapsuccess', onNewCard(), false);


    }

    function errorCallback(message) {

        console.log("there was an error initializing the Triangle APIs");
        console.error(message);
        alert("Error")

    }

    function onNewCard(card) {

        console.log("Scanned card successfully.");

        // Display basic card information to the user
        // various other properties such as cardholderName,
        // activationDate, expiryDate, cardPreferredName, and encryptedAccountNumber
        // may be available.
        var dataToShow = card.cardBrand;
        if (card.cardholderName != undefined) {
            dataToShow += "\n" + card.cardholderName;
        }
        dataToShow += "\n" + card.lastFourDigits;
        alert(dataToShow);

    }

    function onTapDetect() {
        console.log("Detected new tap.");

    }


    function onTapError(error) {

        console.log("Error processing contactless card.");
        console.error(error);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
navigator.triangle.initialize(
    "My Application ID",
    "Access Key",
    "SecretKey",
    succcessCallack,    // remove ()
    errorCallback       // remove ()
);
```

When you refer to a function by name, you don't need to include the brackets. With brackets it means execute the function and use its returned value.